# Are saddle points considered optimums of a function?

Tags: optimization, terminology

Does the statement *"the method is guaranteed to reach a local optimum"* imply that the optimization method is guaranteed to obtain a solution which is either a local maximum or minimum but not a saddle point?

As far as I understood, the term *extremum* refers only to maxima and minima. So the question can be rephrased as "Does *optimum = extremum* in optimization literature?".

Comment: The saddle point of the Lagrangian of a convex optimization problem is an optimal primal-dual pair.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

A local optimum is the optimal (either max or min depending on the problem) in some neighborhood. A saddle point is neither a local max nor a local min.

An optimum is an extremum, but an extremum isn't necessarily an optimum. For example, if you are trying to optimize the dimensions of a box to get the most volume for a set surface area, an extremum (a minimum) might be $0$, but this certainly isn't optimal.